# How do I instantiate a group of objects from a text file?

Tags: python

I have some log files that look like many lines of the following:

```
<tickPrice tickerId=0, field=2, price=201.81, canAutoExecute=1>
<tickSize tickerId=0, field=3, size=25>
<tickSize tickerId=0, field=8, size=534349>
<tickPrice tickerId=0, field=2, price=201.82, canAutoExecute=1>
```

I need to define a class of type tickPrice or tickSize. I will need to decide which to use before doing the definition.

What would be the Pythonic way to grab these values? In other words, I need an effective way to reverse str() on a class.

The classes are already defined and just contain the presented variables, e.g., `tickPrice.tickerId`. I'm trying to find a way to extract these values from the text and set the instance attributes to match.

Edit: Answer

This is what I ended up doing-

```
with open(commandLineOptions.simulationFilename, "r") as simulationFileHandle:
    for simulationFileLine in simulationFileHandle:
        (date, time, msgString) = simulationFileLine.split("\t")
        if ("tickPrice" in msgString):
            msgStringCleaned = msgString.translate(None, ''.join("<>,"))
            msgList = msgStringCleaned.split(" ")
            msg = message.tickPrice()
            msg.tickerId = int(msgList[1][9:])
            msg.field = int(msgList[2][6:])
            msg.price = float(msgList[3][6:])
            msg.canAutoExecute = int(msgList[4][15:])
        elif ("tickSize" in msgString):
            msgStringCleaned = msgString.translate(None, ''.join("<>,"))
            msgList = msgStringCleaned.split(" ")
            msg = message.tickSize()
            msg.tickerId = int(msgList[1][9:])
            msg.field = int(msgList[2][6:])
            msg.size = int(msgList[3][5:])
        else:
            print "Unsupported tick message type"
```

Comment: What would such a class look like?

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiante instances of the classes that are already defined?  Or how to define dynamic classes on demand for these values?  Either way, can you demonstate your attempts at solving the problem, rather than a data sample with a (vague) spec?

Comment: I would define both classes.  Then store them in a dictionary with their name as the key.  In their constructor do a `setattr` for each item packed in its `kwargs`. Clear enough?  ;) maybe not the best way

Comment: Classes are already defined. That's not what I'm struggling with. I'm trying to find the best way to grab a string containing "tickerId=0, field=2, price=201.81, canAutoExecute=1" and define each named variable it's resective value.

Comment: I can't help but feel the root of the problem is that you can't decide whether you're logging messages or serializing objects. Might make your life a whole lot easier to use the standard library's JSON or pickle, or the cheese shop's [jsonpickle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpickle/0.9.2).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you want to dynamically create objects in your namespace, but the following will at least dynamically create objects based on your loglines:

Take your line:

```
line = '<tickPrice tickerId=0, field=2, price=201.81, canAutoExecute=1>'
```

Remove chars that aren't interesting to us, then split the line into a list:

```
line = line.translate(None, ''.join('<>,'))
line = line.split(' ')
```

Name the potential class attributes for convenience:

```
line_attrs = line[1:]
```

Then create your object (name, base tuple, dictionary of attrs):

```
tickPriceObject = type(line[0], (object,), { key:value for key,value in [at.split('=') for at in line_attrs]})()
```

Prove it works as we'd expect:

```
print(tickPriceObject.field)
# 2
```

Comment: `line = line.split(' ')` is equal to `line = line.split()`

Comment: @KevinGuan yeah -- I used the separator to draw attention to what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Approaching the problem with regex, but with the same result as tristan's excellent answer (and stealing his use of the `type` constructor that I will never be able to remember)

```
import re

class_instance_re = re.compile(r"""
        <(?P<classname>\w[a-zA-Z0-9]*)[ ]
        (?P<arguments>
          (?:\w[a-zA-Z0-9]*=[0-9.]+[, ]*)+
        )>""", re.X)

objects = []

for line in whatever_file:
    result = class_instance_re.match(line)
    classname = line.group('classname')
    arguments = line.group('arguments')
    new_obj = type(classname, (object,),
                   dict([s.split('=') for s in arguments.split(', ')]))
    objects.append(new_obj)
```